# Javascript: Detecting changes to an element's position relative to the document

Tags: javascript, dom, web-frontend, mutation-observers

I'm putting together an interactive in Javascript/HTML that draws splines connecting two HTML elements. My current approach is to locate the two HTML elements relative to the document using .getBoundingClientRect().left + window.scrollX etc, then create an svg element with position:absolute to cover the two elements and draw the splines within that svg (if there's a better way of doing this, feel free to let me know).

My issue is that I need to detect every time the position of either element changes relative to the document so I can recalculate the svgs. Similar questions suggest detecting changes to the DOM with MutationObservers and detecting resizes to the window, but I feel like I'd still be missing some case that could cause the svg and elements to become uncoupled.

So, is there a complete (and ideally elegant) way of detecting changes to an element's position relative to the document? Is there a guarantee that the only way to change an element's position relative to the document is a window resize or change to the DOM? Am I stuck just using setInterval?

Comment: Should be possible via IntersectionObserver.

Comment: Looks like IntersectionObserver only handles ancestor-descendent intersections. If it handled overlap of arbitrary elements this would work for me.

Comment: Without seeing the current code I still think it should be possible to use IntersectionObserver to get notified when those elements change their position.